# How to set the colour of FloatingActionButton using AppCompat

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

Using the material design support library:

```
com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.+
com.android.support:design:23.1.+
```

I created a new FloatingActionButton as such:

```
FloatingActionButton button = new FloatingActionButton(context);
button.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
```

This basically worked, but the on an Android 4.4.4 device result is a button with a green edge to it (see image). I note that the green edge is the default colour of the button before using setBackgroundTintList().

[image]

On an Android L device the button looks correct (without the green edge).

How can I set the colour correctly to remove this green edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

to your `FloatingActionButton` in XML.

Comment: Ok yes, this works - thanks. I would have preferred a non-XML option but seems like you can't yet do this programmatically.